# vertical-align only one inline block element

Tags: html, css

I have 3 inline block elements, an image and two pieces of text. I would like to modify the class for only the image such that it is middle aligned while the other two text blocks remain top aligned. It seems to only work if I set `.subImg` to have `vertical-align:top;` and `.subsection` to have `vertical-align:middle;` but not the the other way around. Why is this and how could I fix it? Thanks

Here's the code:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfhbh234/)

### HTML

```
<div id="about">
    <div class="section">
            <img class="subImg" src="https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg" alt="image">
            <div class="subsection">
                <h2>Blah</h2>
                <hr>
                <p>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br></p>
            </div>
            <div class="subsection">
                <h2>Blah</h2>
                <hr>
                <p> blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.section{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#fdfdfd;
 }

.subsection{
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 20%;
}

.subImg{
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: The vertical align piece is answered here I believe, is this what you mean in your question?: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/n8omjz1f/2/)

The vertical-align property in CSS controls how elements set next to each other on a line are lined up.

Add div (vmid) with vertical align middle so this div and the image are middle aligned and inside vmid put the vertical aligned top element.

HTML

```
<div id="about">
  <div class="section">
    <img class="subImg" src="https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg" alt="image">
    <div class="vmid">
      <div class="subsection">
        <h2>Blah</h2>
        <hr>
        <p> blah
          <br>blah
          <br>blah
          <br>blah
          <br>blah
          <br>blah
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="subsection">
        <h2>Blah</h2>
        <hr>
        <p> blah
          <br>blah
          <br>blah
          <br>blah
          <br>blah
          <br>blah
          <br>blah
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.section {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

.subsection {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 20%;
}

.subImg {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 20%;
}

.vmid {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This definitely works, although when resizing the window the image can appear on top of the two text blocks. I was able to achieve a more responsive solution using 
`.subImg{
 position: relative;
 top:10%;
 max-height: 80%;
}`

It's not perfectly centered, but it won't jump around when the window is resized

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for this.

```
.section{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

and for the image align it to center

```
.subImg{
  align-self: center;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/rema/pen/JGLQdb)

### Support

Take note of the flexbox support. It really good now but IE 9 and below do not support it.

[Can I Use It](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `display: table` property on the parent of the elements you want to vertically align. Here's an updated fiddle with some adjustments to the HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/ud14uhub/

```
<div id="about">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="subImgwrap">
       <img class="subImg" src="https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg" alt="image">
     </div>
     <div class="subsection">
       <h2>Blah</h2>
       <hr>
       <p>  blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br></p>
     </div>
     <div class="subsection">
       <h2>Blah</h2>
       <hr>
       <p>  blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br></p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.section{
    width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#fdfdfd;
  display: table;
}

.subsection, .subImgwrap {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}

.subsection{
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
}
.subImgwrap {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.subImg{
  text-align: left;
  width: 100px;
}
```

I wrapped the `subImg` into a wrapping div, which I've used to vertically align and not the image itself. The immediate parent of both `.subsection` and `.subImgwrap` I set to `display: table`, and set the children to `display: table-cell`. This makes vertical aligning much easier and more robust across all browsers.